# Visual Studio (Xamarin): 'MediaPlayer' does not contain a definition for 'Create'

Tags: c#, xamarin, android-mediaplayer

I use 'using Android.Media' but I get the error: "MediaPlayer" does not contain a definition for 'Create'. Only MediaPlayer.Equals and MediaPlayer.ReferenceEqual are available. My teammembers have the same code but they don't have the error. What can I do?

Comment: Could you post the code you are having problems with?

Comment: please post you code it will be useful to know what's wrong with you